# completar la declaración de ID de publicidad para aplicaciones Android 13 (Api 33)

Tags: java, android, flutter, admob

Hace unos dias nos ha llegado un correo a quienes tenemos apps con AdMob en PlayStore.
EL mensaje es el siguiente:

> Debes completar la declaración de ID de publicidad para poder
> publicar una aplicación orientada a Android 13 (API 33). Usaremos esta
> declaración con el fin de implementar medidas en Play Console para
> aplicar los cambios sobre el uso de IDs de publicidad en Android 13.
>
> Las aplicaciones orientadas a Android 13 o versiones posteriores que
> utilicen un ID de publicidad deben incluir el permiso
> com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID en el archivo de manifiesto.

Dicho correo o mensaje que sale como advertencia al momento de subir nueva version de App Bundle, el asunto es "Action requested: Declare your Ad ID permission". Seguramente muchos de los nuevos en PlayConsole nos preguntamos de qué se trata y qué es lo que hay que hacer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para solucionar esa advertencia solo es necesario fijarse si tenemos en el AndroidManifest.xml la siguiente linea:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

En caso de no tenerla es porque no tenemos una versión de 20.3.0 o inferior del SDK de AdMob.

Para solucionar, solo es agregar esa linea de permiso de AD_ID y listo.

Para mas informacion pueden revisar https://dranser.com/action-requested-declare-your-ad-id-permission/

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la documentaciòn que incluye la informaciòn que necesitas:

[Requisitos de orientación de Android 12 y 13](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/dai/android-12)

Esta serìa la informaciòn en español:

> Si su aplicación utiliza la versión 3.25.1 o superior del SDK de IMA,
> el SDK ya declara automáticamente el permiso
> `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID` y puede acceder al ID de
> publicidad siempre que esté disponible.
>
> Para las aplicaciones que utilizan la versión 3.24.0 o anterior del
> SDK de IMA y están destinadas a Android 13, debe agregar el permiso
> `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID` en el archivo
> `AndroidManifest.xml` para que el SDK de anuncios de Google Mobile
> acceda a la Identificación de publicidad:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
        ...
    </application>
    <-- Para aplicaciones destinadas a Android 13 o superior y SDK de IMA versión 3.24.0 o inferior -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
</manifest>
```

De acuerdo a lo descrito por la documentaciòn es importante agregar el permiso:

```
 <-- Para aplicaciones destinadas a Android 13 o superior y SDK de IMA versión 3.24.0 o inferior -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```